# Wordpress URL rewrite problem

Tags: filters, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

blog.com/product/somename

In the above URL - how do I tell Wordpress that 'product' is a variable and 'somename' is its value.

Then how do I extract that value and use it inside a function I'll create?

In short I need to: register variable, check url for variable, extract value, use default post template and generate the_content based on that value, but only if there is a value and only for that url.

Right now I'm neither able to register/extract the variable (when I visit the above-mentioned URL I get a 404) nor specify that the_content should only be replaced when the url contains that variable - it simply replaces the content on all regular posts.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
function product_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^product/(\d+)/?$','index.php?product=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_rewrite_rules' );


add_filter( 'query_vars', 'setup_filter_query_vars_product' );
function setup_filter_query_vars_product( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'product';
    return $query_vars;
}


function products_page () {
global $wp_query;
if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product'] )) {
$productvalue = $wp_query->query_vars['product'];

echo "product is $productvalue";
}
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'products_page');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you setting these up, as child pages?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to [register a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). You can call it `products`, and then all posts placed under Products will get the `http://domain.com/products/some-product` rewrite. Once it's its own post type, you can specify a custom template for it, `single-product.php`, and you can add any custom fields, classes, etc. from there.

Comment: I wanted to use the post template so I don't have to edit two templates whenever I make some changes to the design. Is there a way to do so, or I should go ahead and create a new template?

Comment: You can definitely keep the same template if you don't have any extra data to add in. Even if you do, you can do `if ( 'product' == get_post_type() ) {}` in your `single.php`. The body class `body.product` will allow you to add product specific styles as well.

Comment: OK. In that case why doesn't anything work - neither the URL gets registered, nor the if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['product'] )) condition is being honored? I'm completely in the dark. Everything seems like what others are doing.

Comment: Is the product loading? Also, use `get_post_type()` or `$wp_query->query_vars['post_type']`, it would never be `$wp_query->query_vars['product']`.

Comment: Why `$wp_query->query_vars['post_type']` when I don't have a `post_type` variable anywhere? What I want `http://domain.com/products/some-product` to be converted to/interpreted as is this `http://domain.com/index.php?product=some-product` then I can tell Wordpress to extract the value and generate the_content whenever someone calls the `?product` variable.

Comment: If you set up a custom post type, you don't need any of the rewrite code you have above. It will automatically generate the `post_type` value for you, and from there you can get the post slug using the `ID`